# idevicerestore: command not found

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I'm having trouble running `idevicerestore` on my Ubuntu 16.4 , other commands run just fine, like `ideviceinfo` but when i try restoring my device through `idevicerestore -e <file name.ipsw` that's when it gives me `idevicerestore: command not found`

is there anything i can do about this?

Comment: How did you install `idevicerestore`? unlike `ideviceinfo`, it doesn't seem to be one of the utilities provided by the `libimobiledevice-utils` package

Comment: i downloaded the whole package, and installed following its instructions and running `./autogen.sh` also running `make and make install`. i don`t know where could i have gone wrong through the process.

Comment: Well there's not much to suggest apart from (1) making sure it is installed where the build configurator said it would be (probably `/usr/local/bin` by default) and (2) checking that location is on your `PATH`

Comment: ohk, How do i check the location?

Comment: `ls /usr/bin` ... or `find /usr -name idevicerestore`. Are you sure the build / install succeeded btw? It would have been necessary to build / install `libirecovery` first I think, which I see no mention of in your question or comments.

Comment: `libirecovery` was installed successfully, but now it worked. i had to remove `idevicerestore` then install it again. i think there was some interruptions along the process. thank you very much for your help.